# How to show a div when an anchor is active?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm looking for a way to show a div when an anchor is clicked. 
I've got a html5/php form on my page that when submitted takes the user to an anchor placed in the div with a thank you message and this is the only way to activate that link. 
That's the div I'm trying to display:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <span id="thankyou"></span>
  <p>Than you for your message. I will be in touch soon.</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to change(maybe using CSS) the display:none for when the anchor is active?

Answer (score 0):

You can try hiding and showing the element using javascript. Here is a link to a reference example
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/

You could also use jQuery .hide() .show()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you question correctly, but if you would like to display a child element when the parent is hoovered something like this should work:

```
.link-message {
   display:none;
}
a:hover .link-message {
   display:inline-block;
}

<a href="#">
  Sample Link 
  <div class="link-message">
    <span id="thankyou"></span>
    <p>Than you for your message. I will be in touch soon.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

You should also be able to absolute position the link-message container in your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('dividhere').style.display='';">Show/Hide</a>
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but no one got to the point, so I'll give you my two cents.

```
<style>
.popup { position: fixed; display: block; visibility: hidden; /* other styles */ }
#anchorid:target+.popup { visibility: visible; }
</style>
```

Then

```
<a href="#anchorid">Click to see the popup corresponding to the id</a>

<a name="anchorid" id="anchorid" class="clicked"></a>
<div class="popup">
  The contents of this popup is hidden until the link above is clicked.
</div>

<a name="anchorid2" id="anchorid2" class="clicked"></a>
<div class="popup">
  The contents of this popup is also hidden, and remains hidden until the anchor immediately preceding it becomes actively targeted.
</div>
```

Now what happens:
When a user clicks the first link, the href contains only an anchor, so it is simply appended to the URL in the address bar, without reloading the page. The anchor with id `#anchorid` is now considered targeted by CSS. Combining it with `+.popup` means "select any element which comes right after the element which has this id when that id is also the currently targeted anchor". The '+' is mandatory, because an achor element is considered to contain only flow elements, which a div is not.